# SqlDataAdapter Parameter size for `int` and `datetime`

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter

When creating a `SqlDataAdapter` and adding parameters, what should the size be for `Int` and `DateTime` types?
Is there a reason `size` is required?

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "insert into MyTable (id, created, stuff) values (@id, @created, @stuff)",
    connection);
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, ?????, "id");
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@created", SqlDbType.DateTime, ????, "created");
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@stuff", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250, "stuff");
```

Added to answer a question about where the data is originating: (In original part of post, I renamed "description" to "stuff")

```
    public static DataSet dumpETEvents()
    {
        DataSet ret = new DataSet();
        SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand(
            "select id, created, description from ETEvents",
            DbDatabase.connection);
        adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.Add;
        adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
        adapter.Fill(ret);
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: don't worry about the `size` let the database handle it by changing the 
`adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, ?????, "id");` to `adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", paramvalue);` //this is where you are getting the ID value from

Comment: @DJKRAZE how do I specify the source column if I do that?

Comment: where are you passing the `ID` or storing the value of the `ID` that you want to Insert..? is it in a `property, textbox, return value, etc...?`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I added the code that populates where the data is coming from.

Comment: then you need to get at the ret["FieldName"] and pass that var value to the Parameters.AddWithValue()` method for that first line and so on for the next 2 insert lines their perspective FieldName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size doesn't matter!

"For fixed length data types, the value of Size is ignored. It can be retrieved for informational purposes, and returns the maximum amount of bytes the provider uses when transmitting the value of the parameter to the server."

See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter.size%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Size does matter in case you are using types with dynamic length like varchar. If you just ignore away size, you might end with hundreads or thousands of different execution plans in Sql Server where the size has been added automatically depending of the length of the values that have been passed. You would not want this to happen. I would always suggeest to pass types and size precisely.

Answer (score 2):

There are overloads to [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyaybfa1.aspx) that do not take a size, so this is **not** always required.

For integer and `DATETIME` fields, since these have fixed sizes, this is not required.

You should also take a look at [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx):

> `AddWithValue` replaces the `SqlParameterCollection.Add` method that takes a `String` and an `Object`.

Comment: That's what I originally suggested LOL